# Unable to send data in response to the view in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, callback, httprequest

I am trying to create a simple web application which fires a http.request call, get the data and display it over to the html(ejs here). I am able to fire the request, get the data, massage it etc.. but unable to pass it to the view. Sample code is as below:

```
var searchData = [];
router.post('/',requesthandler);
function requesthandler(req,res){
    var options = {
        host: url,
        port: 9999,
        path: qstring,
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var reqget = http.request(options,responsehandler);
    reqget.end();
    console.log('Rendering now:............................ '); 
    res.render('result',{title: 'Results Returned',searchdata : searchData});
}
function responsehandler(ress) {    
    console.log('STATUS: ' + ress.statusCode);
    ress.on('data', function (chunk) {
        output += chunk;
        console.log('BODY: ' );
    });
    /* reqget.write(output); */
    ress.on('end',parseresponse);   
}
function parseresponse(){
    var data = JSON.parse(output);
    console.log(data.responseHeader);
    // populate searchData here from data object
     searchData.push({//some data});
}
function errorhandler(e) {
     console.error(e);
}
module.exports = router;
```

Problem is I a unable to pass the objeect searchData to the view via res.render();
'Rendering now: ...........' gets executed before execution starts in parseresponse() and so the page is displayed without the data which seems to be in conjuction with using callbacks, So how can I pass the data object to the view once the searchData is loaded in parseresponse().
PS: I am able to print all console statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define res variable globally:

```
var res;      
function requesthandler(req,resObj){
    res = resObj;//set it to the resObj
}
```

wrap res.render inside a function like this:

```
function renderPage(){
    res.render('result',{title: 'Results Returned',searchdata : searchData});
}
```

then in parseresponse function do this:

```
function parseresponse(){
    var data = JSON.parse(output);
    searchData.push({some data});
    renderPage();
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.